# Problems with registration User using HTML POST in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, http

I have an issue with the registration of a new user using `HTTP POST` and `Web API` made with ASP.NET.

Here is my `AuthController` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebAPI_1.Data;
using WebAPI_1.DTOs;
using WebAPI_1.Models;

namespace WebAPI_1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAuthRepository _repository;

        public AuthController(IAuthRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        [HttpPost("{register}")]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDTO userForRegisterDTO)
        {
            UserForRegisterDTO.Username = UserForRegisterDTO.Username.ToLower();

            if (await _repository.UserExist(UserForRegisterDTO.Username))
                return BadRequest("Użytkownik o takiej nazwie już istnieje");

            var userToCreate = new User { Username = UserForRegisterDTO.Username };

            var createdUser = await _repository.Register(userToCreate, UserForRegisterDTO.Password);

            return StatusCode(201);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using just `Register(string username, string password)` but with

> Internal Server Error

so I made a DTO to handle this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI_1.DTOs
{
    public class UserForRegisterDTO
    {
        public static string Username { get; set; }
        public static string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But with that I getting another error message:

> 415 unsupported media

in postman with body looking like this:

```
{
    "Username": "Marcin",
    "Password": "password"
}
```

I think my `User` model might be helpful so I was leaving it here:

```
namespace WebAPI_1.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }

        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the sole issue but your route attribute looks incorrect. Should be `[HttpPost("register")]`

Comment: thx for review i will change it

Comment: Let me know if that works

Comment: It not works, but thanks.

Comment: Does it hit your controller from postman request?

Comment: I'm accually still getting 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: What's the content types set 2 in Postman?

Comment: where can I found it, in headers?

Comment: Yes. It should be application/json

Comment: 415 Unsupported Media points to your request not being specified as JSON format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all Change Media Type On
   `Postman` `Content-Type:application/json` Like below:

[image]

2. Body Should look like below:

[image]

3. Try with below controller action snippet and `[HttpPost("{Register}")]` is absolutely fine.

```cs
        [HttpPost("{Register}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<object>> Register([FromBody]User userModel)
        { 
            try
            {
                UserForRegisterDTO.Username = userModel.Username;

                UserForRegisterDTO.Username = userModel.Password;

                return UserForRegisterDTO.Username;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;

        }
```

4. I have modify your model a bit. You can change it once it work
   nicely.

```cs
public class UserForRegisterDTO
    {
        public static string Username { get; set; }
        public static string Password { get; set; }
    }

public class User
{

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

> It would hit your controller with no `415 Unsupported Media Type` 
>   error.

Let me know once it work as expected.

Comment: Let me know your update, there are many reasons of this problem.

Comment: Have you tried my sample as it is? Or modified anything?

Comment: Replace this one `[Route("api/[Auth]")]` instead of  `[Route("api/[controller]")]`

Comment: Done already, now i got this exception: https://pastebin.com/GQxpFrg6

Comment: Show me your   `routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "defaultApi",
                    template: "api/{controller}/{action}"
                );` code and project screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Route attribute like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDTO userForRegisterDTO)
{
 ...
}
```

While sending a request through postman you url would be :

*http://localhost:yourport/api/auth/register*